# Bind list to drop down in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to add data text field and data value field to drop down list from Lis. How can I do that?

So far I do like this but it got an error:

> DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name
>   'cos_name'.

This is my data access layer:

```
public List<String> GetAllCourseName()
{
    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
    objsqlconn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select cos_ID, cos_name from course_details", objsqlconn); 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
    da.Fill(ds, "course_details"); 

    List<String> courseName = new List<String>();

    foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["course_details"].Rows)
    {
        courseName.Add(row["cos_ID"].ToString());
        courseName.Add(row["cos_name"].ToString());
    }
    return courseName;
}
```

This is my Form load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        FillCourseName();
    }   
}
public void FillCourseName()
{
    ddcoursename.DataSource = objda.GetAllCourseName();
    ddcoursename.DataTextField = "cos_name";
    ddcoursename.DataValueField = "cos_ID";
    ddcoursename.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: This is the error : DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'cos_name'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dotnetom has a good answer.  However, if you would still like to use a List instead you can still do it by taking another approach like this:

Create a new class for your data...

```
public class CourseDetailsClass
{
    public string cos_ID { get; set; }
    public string cos_name { get; set; }
}
```

And then modify your GetAllCourseName method like this...

```
public List<CourseDetailsClass> GetAllCourseName()
{
   SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
   objsqlconn.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select cos_ID, cos_name from course_details", objsqlconn); 
   DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
   da.Fill(ds, "course_details"); 

   List<CourseDetailsClass> courseName = new List<CourseDetailsClass>();

   foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["course_details"].Rows)
   {
        courseName.Add(new CourseDetailsClass
        {
            cos_ID = row["cos_ID"].ToString(),
            cos_name = row["cos_name"].ToString()
        });         
    }

     return courseName;
}
```

That should also work for you.  You can then use the list as a datasource and it will now be able to find both the `TextDataField` and `TextValueField` fields.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your method `GetAllCourseName` returns a list of strings, which obviously do not have properties `cos_name` and `cos_ID`. Instead you can return a data table and bind it to a dropdown list:

```
public DataTable GetAllCourseName()
{
   SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
   objsqlconn.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select cos_ID, cos_name from course_details", objsqlconn); 
   DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
   da.Fill(ds, "course_details"); 

   return ds.Tables["course_details"];
}
```

The `FillCourseName` method does not need to change.